# CreateBlobStream, Stream Size

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, bde

My Code:

```
 stream := qry.CreateBlobStream(qry.FieldByName('aaa'), bmRead);
```

The record in aaa is actually bigger than the stream's size,which is always 32786.Why?

Comment: Do we need more details? Like Delphi version. Which DB framework? Which DB?

Comment: And I Mean stream's size is alway's 32768 bytes;And the Real lenth of record AAA is much bigger!

Comment: And framework? BDE I presume?

Comment: Yes, TQuery  @David Heffernan

Comment: The BDE is like smoking.  If you aren't doing it, don't start.  If you are doing it, quit right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my web searches, you need to increase the BLOB SIZE parameter in the BDE administrator:

- http://www.borlandtalk.com/blobstream-limited-to-32768-bytes-vt34635.html
- http://www.delphigroups.info/2/63/235340.html

The first of these threads suggests an alternative approach of setting RequestLive of the TQuery to be True.

The second thread dates from 1902 which would appear to be a rare sighting in the wild of the Y2K bug!

Comment: Thanks，it works! I just changed BLOB SIZE to 128!@David Heffernan